# Filtering objects from two array of objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

I am trying to filter objects from two array of objects on the basis of name along with few conditions using lodash. Here are the arrays

```
var param1 = [{'name': 'sa', 'value':'sample'},
              {'name': 'sam', 'value':''}];

var param2 = [{'name': 's1', 'value':'ex1'},
           {'name': 's2', 'value':'ex2'},
           {'name': 's3', 'value':'ex3'},
           {'name': 'sa', 'value':'ex4'}];
```

I wanted to check the objects of param1[by name] existence in param2, if so return the param1 object along with the rest of the objects left within param2. So the final result has to be some thing like this:

```
result= [{'name': 's1', 'value':'ex1'},
         {'name': 's2', 'value':'ex2'},
         {'name': 's3', 'value':'ex3'},
         {'name': 'sa', 'value':'sample'}];
```

I have tried with couple of lodash functions such as `_.filter`, `_.map`, `_.difference` but am clueless on how to chain this functionality and get the appropriate result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lodash with [`_.forEach`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#forEach) and [`_.find`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#find).

```js
var param1 = [{'name': 'sa', 'value':'sample'}, {'name': 'sam', 'value':''}];
var param2 = [{'name': 's1', 'value':'ex1'}, {'name': 's2', 'value':'ex2'}, {'name': 's3', 'value':'ex3'}, {'name': 'sa', 'value':'ex4'}];

_.forEach(param1, a => {
    var o = _.find(param2, b => a.name === b.name);
    if (o) {
        o.value = a.value;
    }
});

console.log(param2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Plain ES6 Javascript

```js
var param1 = [{'name': 'sa', 'value':'sample'}, {'name': 'sam', 'value':''}];
var param2 = [{'name': 's1', 'value':'ex1'}, {'name': 's2', 'value':'ex2'}, {'name': 's3', 'value':'ex3'}, {'name': 'sa', 'value':'ex4'}];

param1.forEach(a => {
    var o = param2.find(b => a.name === b.name);
    if (o) {
        o.value = a.value;
    }
});

console.log(param2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Lodash, a couple of ways spring to mind using some of the array functions that it offers:

```
function comparator(a, b) {
    return a.name === b.name;
}

// First way.
var res = _.intersectionWith(_.unionWith(param1, param2, comparator), param2, comparator);

// Second way.
var res1 = _.differenceWith(param2, _.intersectionWith(param1, param2, comparator), _.isEqual).concat(_.intersectionWith(param2, param1, comparator));
```

The first solution is a bit more obvious:

1. Perform the union of both arrays comparing them by name (values are chosen from the first array in which the object with the same name lies).
2. Intersect the resulting array with the second array (comparing by name too) so that we can get rid of objects of param1 that aren't on param2.

The second solution is a bit more cumbersome but uses difference (mentioned in your post):

1. Intersect param1 and param2 by name to get common objects from param2.
2. Substract the result to param2 by equality (we'll end up with all objects in param2 that doesn't have the name in param1).
3. Concat to the substraction the intersection between param2 and param1 by name (we're adding the objects in param1 that have the same name in param2).

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmuqvevs/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Dont think you will need lodash for it, You can use array [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
to execute it

```
var param1 = [{
  'name': 'sa',
  'value': 'sample'
}, {
  'name': 'sam',
  'value': ''
}];

var param2 = [{
  'name': 's1',
  'value': 'ex1'
}, {
  'name': 's2',
  'value': 'ex2'
}, {
  'name': 's3',
  'value': 'ex3'
}, {
  'name': 'sa',
  'value': 'ex4'
}];

param1.forEach(function(item) {
     param2.forEach(function(item2){
      if(item.name ==item2.name){
       item2.value = item.value
     }
   })

})

console.log(param2)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/u5Lfyw8j/)